# Global jQuery dialog variable not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, global-variables, jquery-ui-dialog

When I call the function, the dialog doesn't work.
If I move the dialog construction into the showtimes_list function, everything works fine.

I thought that variables declared outside a function were global in context?

```
var dialog_list = $("<div></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 300, width: 720,
});

function showtimes_list(sid){
    dialog_list.html("");
    $.get("ajax_showtimes.php?sid="+sid, function(data){
            dialog_list.html(data);
        }
    );

    dialog_list.dialog("open");
}
```

---Edit---

This is being called from an onClick to showtimes_list.

---Edit---

This is working:

```
function showtimes_list(sid){
    $("#stl").dialog("open");
    $("#stl").html("");
    $.get("ajax_showtimes.php?sid="+sid, function(data){
            $("#stl").html(data);
        }
    );    
}

$(function(){
    $('<div id="stl"></div>').appendTo(document.body).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300, width: 720,
    });    
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you elaborate on what *doesn't* work?

Comment: Not really enough to go on here.  Are you calling this in the document.ready() function?  Or is this just in a script tag?

Comment: @Pointy typo'd it.. sorry. It doesn't work when called without moving the variable setup into the function.

Comment: Is there any Console output about an error of somesort, or try add a div element to your html page with an attribute id and then select that element as your dialog_list.

Comment: Are you sure the value of dialog_list is not modified at any time between where it's declared there or when the click event fires? With the code as you've written it, `dialog_list` is definitely in context in `showtimes_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new empty div, add the div to the document, e.g.:

```
<body>
   <div id="dialog">
      <div id="dialogContent"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Then, your script will become

```
var dialog_list = $("#dialog").dialog({ });
```

Then, when you want to change the HTML of that element, instead of changing the dialog itself, you'd want to change the dialogContent element:

```
function showtimes_list(sid){    
     var content = $("#dialogContent");
     content.html("");
    $.get("ajax_showtimes.php?sid="+sid, function(data){
            content.html(data);
        }
    );

    dialog_list.dialog("open");
}
```

If you don't want these empty divs in your HTML structure, you should add them to the body dynamically and use classes instead of ids.

Edit: to answer your question as to why it doesn't work when the dialog_list is outside the function, I'd imagine it has something to do with the generated html.

When you call .dialog(), jQuery generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
      <p>Dialog content goes here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

When this is outside of your function, it is called whenever it is encountered in the script... Then, in your function, you change that generated HTML.  It's been a while since I dynamically updated dialog content, but I ran into the same problem, and the generated HTML was the culprit.  I think my solution was to, instead of the nested divs in my original answer, I created the dialog as you did (outside the function), and inside the function, you change the html of the `ui-dialog-content`

For instance:

```
function showtimes_list(sid){
    dialog_list.find('.ui-dialog-content').html("");
    $.get("ajax_showtimes.php?sid="+sid, function(data){
            dialog_list.find('.ui-dialog-content').html(data);
        }
    );

    dialog_list.dialog("open");
}
```